# How to share files with pydrive

Tags: python, pydrive, gdrive

I can't find the way to share Google drive files after I upload them, currently I'm using Python and PyDrive . I'm not even sure if this is even possible.

Sharing is  a Google Drive option, it's allows other users to access use it(read, comment or edit).

Here's my code:
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

ufile = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello.txt'})

ufile.SetContentString('Hello World!')

ufile.Upload()

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `I upload them`, could you upload the file to Google Drive using your script? If you can do, please add your current script in your question. 2. About `share Google drive files`, I cannot understand about this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?